# Getting correct response but data not getting displayed in UI

Tags: asp.net, winforms, web-services, wcf, soap

I have developed a service and its working fine, response is looking exactly same when compared to the data from database, But when the service is being consumed, the UI is breaking, I am getting the error ***"An error occured while retrieving data from database, Is Visible Changed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."*** But in fiddler I have found the correct response. I have the checked the order of the data contract, every thing is in same order. Can someone suggest what might be the issue?

Comment: Post the client side of the code.

Comment: I dont have access to UI, just the service..

Comment: Well, that makes it difficult to troubleshoot. Basically "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." means that there is an object or property, which is not instantiated (it is null) and you are most probably trying to access one of its properties or methods.

Comment: If the service's output is good, then it is possible that the consumer (the UI) has a problem. Also, double check the service's output. Are you missing any property in the result? For example the class might have 20 properties but your service returns values for 19 properties.

Comment: Hi Feryal, When I check the response, I have noticed that "DataContracts" namespace is missing in the response for that operation and all the other operation's response in that are having it, How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service code, you should have this statement:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```

and the data that your service is returning should be defined like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class YourOutPutClassName
{
    [DataMember]
    public string property1 {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't put the code in a comment box, so I am adding it in the answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes Its similar to that, in UI they are adding the namespace, and in the dataContract I have also added the namespace, when I remove the namespace in my DataContract Its working fine.